# require js init do not get called

Tags: javascript, class, requirejs

I define a class according to [john resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) idea about using classes in javascript.

```
define('class', function() {

    var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
    Class.extend = function(prop) {
        var _super = this.prototype;
        initializing = true;
        var prototype = new this();
        initializing = false;
        for (var name in prop) {
            prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
                typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
                (function(name, fn){
                    return function() {
                        var tmp = this._super;
                        this._super = _super[name];
                        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
                        this._super = tmp;
                        return ret;
                    };
                })(name, prop[name]) :
                prop[name];
        }
        function Class() {
            this.self = this;
            if ( !initializing && this.init )
                this.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        Class.prototype = prototype;

        Class.constructor = Class;
        Class.extend = arguments.callee;
        return Class;
    };
    return Class;
   });
```

Then I tried to using it in my requirejs file like below

```
define('popup',['class'],
    function (Class) {

        var popup = Class.extend({

            init: function () {
                console.log('init');
            }

        });
     return popup;
    });
```

I run the code from a simple html according to [requirejs definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

```
<script data-main='script/popup.js' src="script/require.js" ></script>
```

but it never run my constructor i.e. init method

all of my files are in the script folder, therefore I did not define any path config.
the code hitting the class.js and popup.js but it never go to the init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup is not an object, but a function, to get a new object call:

```
var p = new popup();
```

Class.extend return a new constructor not a object instantiated.

ps: before

```
Class.extend = function(prop) {
```

add

```
this.Class = function() {};
```

otherwise Class is undefined.